# Methods Missing When Consuming a Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

My task includes consuming the Web Service Function which I got from WSDL.
After adding reference to WSDL in C# I am unable to find a service request method by simply calling the class.

Instead it has few other methods to use per service which I am unable to understand how to use them: ServiceNameRequest,
ServiceNameResponse, ServiceNameCompletedEventArgs...

Any idea how to utilize the WSDL in c# with this approach?

Comment: Now I am able to get soap methods by adding service reference in C# instead of a Web Reference.
When I try to make a service request using soap client I am getting following error : There was no endpoint listening at http://XXX.... 
Any idea why this is happening?
Services are accessible through SOAP UI.

Comment: It turns out the server was down.
My client is working fine now...
Thanks for your help friends.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a service reference:

Look for ServiceNameClient class.  The operations you are looking for will be off of that.

so say its the User service. There should be a UserClient.  Off of UserClient you should have things like UserClient.Getuser or UserClient.Adduser etc.

Comment: So in this case I have AdduserRequest, AdduserResponse... methods

Comment: You don't see ServiceNameClient?  What kind of reference do you have to the WSDL web or service?  Why don't you post a picture of the reference in object browser.

Comment: Sorry I could not put any images. I just tried WSDL with soap 1.2 version its working as expected and mine WSDL has older soap version does this causing me the problem?